# Update bytea data that was first encoded as a hex char string

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

Given a table with a "blob" column of `bytea` type, that has data that was first encoded as a char string of 'hex' format by the `toString` method of Node's Buffer API ... yes, not the best idea ...

Is it possible to update the data so that the data is decoded from 'hex' and returned to raw bytes?

`decode(blob,'hex')` is not going to work as the blob is still `bytea`, not `text`.

Looking for a possibly 'pure' Postgres (> v12) solution without going back to Node's Buffer API first, but I'll accept the punishment of having to export the data, transform it, and update from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fear not:

```
UPDATE blobs
SET b = decode(encode(b, 'escape'), 'hex');
```

With the `escape` format, the hex digits you stored by mistake will be output as characters, and the `hex` format will interpret pairs of these hex digits as a single byte.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. I did not think that `escape` was a viable format for my data, given that `hex` is the default. Thanks again.